# Measuring the sound level of a stream in dB from command-line

Tags: linux, command-line, pulseaudio

Is it possible to measure the volume of the sound stream currently being played by other programs in **dB** using just command-line? The target audio server is Pulse Audio.

Comment: This doesn't look possible. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2445756/how-can-i-calculate-audio-db-level) to a similar question.